# How to connect to two document in the same collection

Tags: arangodb

In Arango DB how do I build a graph of relations of the documents in one collection? The documentation covers using multi table collection but not how to it inside one collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the requirement is to create a graph using a single vertex collection.

The following example (ArangoShell code) creates a graph named `example`, using a single vertex collection named `v` and an edge collection named `e`:

```
var g = require("org/arangodb/general-graph");
g._create("example", [ { collection: "e", "from": [ "v" ], "to" : [ "v" ] } ]);
g._graph("example");
```

This will bring up this graph definition:

```
[ Graph example EdgeDefinitions: [ 
  "e: [v] -> [v]" 
] VertexCollections: [ ] ]
```

Note that having a separate edge collection is still required, but vertices can be stored in a single collection (as shown above) or in multiple.

Comment: could you please update the doc so this syntax is covered. Is their a way to import a edge collection into a graph?

Comment: I have added such example to the docs. The updated docs will be online with the 2.6 release. Here's the commit for reference: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/commit/7d6f1369d3de4991cf9bcb8816bab5c28ac57195